# jquery scrollTop() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm testing out some jquery in jsfiddle and I have the following code

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 1000px;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.test')scrollTop(500);
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="test">
 <h1>hello world</h1>
</div>
```

Everything appears to be correct according to documentation, but for some reason its not re-positioning my view....
Thanks for the help

**UPDATE**
Had typo

Comment: can u pls post the link to your fiddle?

Comment: does your html has necessary height?

Comment: You have a syntax error here `$('.test.')scrollTop` - is that in your code? Should be `$('.test').scrollTop`. Additionally, that selector is not correct, it has a trailing `.`

Comment: @redflar3 http://jsfiddle.net/bvcxtds/3ymc7u1v/1/

Comment: @RGraham typo when writing the question, still not working here is my test jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bvcxtds/3ymc7u1v/1/

Comment: @helloworld You need to learn how to write a question which is representative of your problem. That fiddle the class is clearly `demo`, but your selector says `div.test` **and** you have set a height on `html, body` but your `div` is still at `height: auto` and therefore cannot be scrolled

Comment: @RGraham ops, forgot to update my jsfiddle heres the new one http://jsfiddle.net/bvcxtds/3ymc7u1v/1/ lol

Comment: $( "html,body" ).scrollTop( 300 );  -- not the class   -- http://jsfiddle.net/8aztp3r7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scrollTop` will only scroll if the target element has a scrollbar. In order to scroll in your example, you need to force the content of the `test` div to overflow it's content, for example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".test" ).scrollTop( 300 );
});
```

```css
/* Give test a fixed height so that it overflows */
.test {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
/* Give the inner container a height which exceeds .test */
.inner {
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
    <div class="inner">
        <h1>lalala</h1>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying for me, ill will mark this question as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
$('.test.')scrollTop(500);
```

use

```
$('.test').scrollTop(500);
```

Comment: sorry that was typo when i was writing the question, still not working here is my jsfiddle